# conditional expression if and or

Tags: r

I have the following expression

```
motherW
```

Which can have as result just one element of the following list

```
s2,s4,s6,s8,s10,s12,s14,s16,haar,d2,d4,d6,d8,d10,d12,d14,d16,d18,c6,c12,c18,c24,
c30,l4,l6,l14,l18
```

I would like to have a conditional expression like the one below (which produces an error. I believe is the use of or / ifesle)

```
B<-If(motherW=="s2" | "s4" | "s6" | "s8" | "s10" | "s12" | "s14" | "s16") 8 ifelse  
(mother=="haar" | "d2" | "d4" | "d6" | "d8" | "d10" | "d12" | "d14" | "d16" | "d18") 9 
ifelse (motherW=="c6" | "c12" | "c18" | "c24" | "c30")) 5 ifelse (c(motherW=="l2" | "l4" 
| "l6" | "l14" | "l18") 5 else 0
```

which can provide depending on the result of motherW any of the following results - if the  s series 8 if the d series 9, if the c series 5 and if the l series 5.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the correct way to use `if` and `else`:

```
B <- if (motherW %in% c("s2", "s4", "s6", "s8", "s10", "s12", "s14", "s16")) {
  8
} else {
  if (motherW %in% c("haar", "d2", "d4", "d6", "d8", "d10", "d12", "d14", "d16", "d18")) {
    9
  } else {
    if (motherW %in% c("c6", "c12", "c18", "c24", "c30", "l2", "l4", "l6", "l14", "l18")) {
      5
    } else {
      0
    }
  }  
}
```

---

*Update*:

A much shorter way is the following one:

```
tab <- tab <- c(s = 5, d = 9, h = 9, c = 5, l = 5)
sus <- substr(motherW, 1, 1)
B <- if (any(sus == names(tab))) tab[sus] else 0
```

Comment: +1 The shorter solution would work if the "d" list didn't include "haar".  You can fix it by adding "h" to `setNames()` with a value of 9: `tab <- setNames(c(8, 9, 5, 5, 9), c("s", "d", "c", "l", "h"))`

Comment: I think `tab <- c(s = 5, d = 9, h = 9, c = 5, l = 5)` makes the connection between lookup and value more clear

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax is incorrect. For one, you need to write OR conditions like

```
motherW=="s2" | motherW=="s4" | ...
```

Instead of writing it all like that, you could use `%in%`

One possible solution, using nested `ifelse` conditions is

```
B <- ifelse(motherW %in% c("s2","s4","s6","s8","s10","s12","s14","s16"),
    8,
    ifelse(motherW %in% c("haar","d2","d4","d6","d8","d10","d12","d14","d16","d18"),
        9,
        ifelse(motherW %in% c("c6","c12","c18","c24","c30"),
            5,
            ifelse(motherW %in% c("l2","l4","l6","l14","l18"), 5, 0))))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
B <- 8*(motherW %in% c("s2","s4","s6","s8","s10","s12","s14","s16"))+
     9*(motherW %in% c("haar","d2","d4","d6","d8","d10","d12","d14","d16","d18"))+
     5*(motherW %in% c("c6","c12","c18","c24","c30"))+
     5*(motherW %in% c("l2","l4","l6","l14","l18"))
```

This works because R converts `TRUE` and `FALSE` to 1 and 0 in mathematical operations.  Since your lists are non-overlaping you can just multiply each TRUE/FALSE statement by the number it should get if it's in that list, and if it isn't in any of the lists, `B` will get 0.